# Python IDLE terminal seem to be stuck

Tags: python, python-idle

I am not sure how to describe this issue. All of a sudden my IDLE terminal seem to be stuck like the way the showed in the snapshot.
I uninstalled and installed the python. Not sure what the issue is.
[image]

Comment: Does it happen for any other commands?

Comment: Yes for everything.  In fact even if I just press enter

Comment: In the short term, start IDLE from a Command Prompt command line with `python -m idlelib.idle`.  Do you see and error messages before or after hitting `Enter`?  The freeze might possibly be due  to a corrupt file in the .idlerc directory in your home directory (C:/Users/Yourname on Win7, 8, 10).  A desperation measure is to delete them all (losing any customization you have done) or even the directory itself.  In the longer term, I strongly recommend upgrading to 2.7.11, with over 1000 bug fixes compared to 2.7.3.  On Windows, there is hardly any reason not to do so.

Comment: Also, try to remember what you did to your system between IDLE working and  not working.  Adding a file that masks a stdlib file, such as random.py, might be an issue.  The problematic locations depend on how you start IDLE.